# Using a method within apply

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

To find the maximum of an array, an easy way is

```
Math.max.apply(null, myArray)
```

However, assuming that `myArray` contains complex numbers, and each complex number has a method `magnitude` that computes the length of the complex number, is there a simple way to find the maximum of the magnitude of the entries in `myArray`? I could of course do a `loop` or a function, but my guess is that javascript has a nice one-line solution...

Here is a short code snippet with all the elements:

```js
function Complex(re, im) {
  this.real = re;
  this.imag = im;
}

Complex.prototype.magnitude = function() {
  return Math.sqrt(this.real * this.real + this.imag * this.imag);
};

var a = new Array(1, 2, 3);
ra = Math.max.apply(null, a); // works fine

var b = new Array(new Complex(1, 2), new Complex(1, 3), new Complex(1, 4));
rb = Math.max.apply(null, b)

console.log(ra)
console.log(rb) //NaN without surprise
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of magnitudes to apply `Math.max` to.

```js
function Complex(re, im) {
    this.real = re;
    this.imag = im;
}
Complex.prototype.magnitude = function() {
  return Math.sqrt(this.real*this.real + this.imag*this.imag);
};
let b = [new Complex(1,2), new Complex(1,3),  new Complex(1,4)];
let res = Math.max(...b.map(x => x.magnitude()));
console.log(res);
```

A couple of notes:

- You can directly use `[]` to create an array. There is no need to use `new Array()`.
- You can use [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of `Function#apply` here.

Answer (score 1):

Was going to suggest the same, gave the code a little bit modern syntax as well, so **Unmitigated** beat me to it, but yes use **map**:

```
class Complex {

  constructor(real, imag) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;
  }

  magnitude() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.real * this.real + this.imag * this.imag);
  };
}

let a = [1, 2, 3]
ra = Math.max(...a) // works fine

var b = [new Complex(1, 2), new Complex(1, 3), new Complex(1, 4)];
rb = Math.max(...b.map(x => x.magnitude()));

console.log(ra)
console.log(rb) // works now
```

Yes, you can use spread syntax instead of **apply**, and brackets instead of **new Array**, and you can use a class syntax since Complex is really a class.

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding the class. Neater!