# What is wrong with this inverse FFT implementation

Tags: javascript, fft

I am using the following implementation of an inverse Fast Fourier transform (FFT) for images in which the image of size *N* by *N* is stored in a vector of length *N* x *N* (with *N* a square number). When I feed this implementation a matrix of zeros except two 1s, one a few rows above the center and symmetrically below the center, the inverse is correctly an image with vertical bands whose frequency matches the position of the 1s.

However, when the 1s are on the left and on the right of the center, I get horizontal bands, but they are not perfectly horizontal. They have a very small slope. When I do exactly the same in Mathematica with the build-in `InverseFourier` function, the bands are very precisely horizontal.

Is there something wrong in the JavaScript implementation below? The relevant code is given below; a complete MWE is available at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97ca0dkg/1/)

```
function invFFT_radix2(out, start, input, N, offset, s ) {
    if (N === 1) {
        out[start] = input[offset];
    } else {
        invFFT_radix2(out, start,     input, N/2, offset,   2*s);
        invFFT_radix2(out, start+N/2, input, N/2, offset+s, 2*s);
        for (var k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
            var twiddle = cisExp(2*Math.PI*k/N);
            var t = out[start+k];
            out[start+k]     = t.plus ( twiddle.times(out[start+k+N/2]) );
            out[start+k+N/2] = t.minus( twiddle.times(out[start+k+N/2]) );
        }
    }
}
```

called with

```
invFFT_radix2(out, 0, input, input.length, 0, 1 )
```

in which `input` is the input vector, and `out` contains the result. All the entries are `Complex` numbers (as per [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150753/5181513)) and the function `cisExp` is defined as

```
function cisExp(x) { // e^ix = cos x + i*sin x
    return new Complex(Math.cos(x), Math.sin(x));
}
```

As a comparision, this is the magnified top of the image with the JSFiddle
[image]

and with Mathematica
[image]

The JS image begins on the left with a white line which becomes black on the right.

Comment: I’m not nearly familiar enough with the math, but FWIW the result with Mathematica’s built-in `InverseFourier` looks exactly the same.

Comment: @Ry I added magnifications of the top of the images with Mathematica and with the current program. The slope is small but clearly there for the JS program.

Comment: Show your Mathematica? What I meant was that I get a slope with Mathematica.

Comment: @Ry: Uh, very bizzarre. This is what I did in Mathematica: `ss = Array[0 &, {256, 256}];
ss[[106, 128]] = ss[[150, 128]] = 1;
Image[Abs[InverseFourier[ss]]/Max[Abs[InverseFourier[ss]]], 
 ImageSize -> 16 72]`

Comment: Seems that that’s a 2D IDFT. (To see the 1D slope, `ImagePad[Image[Normalize[Abs[ArrayReshape[InverseFourier[Flatten[Transpose[l]]],{256,256}]],Max]],2]`.)

Comment: @Ry: yes, you are indeed correct. Still looking on how the above program should be rewritten.

Comment: If N is an odd number, `start+k+N/2` can be non-integer, so `out[start+k+N/2]` may cause a problem here.

Comment: @grsngky the input **has** to have a power-of-2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D [inverse] DFT is the 1D version on one axis then the other, so you could do, for example,

```
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
    invFFT_radix2(out, y * WIDTH, ss, WIDTH, y * WIDTH, 1);
  }
  ss = out.slice();
  transpose(ss);
}
```

where

```
const WIDTH = 256;
const HEIGHT = 256;
const swap = (arr, i, j) => {
  const t = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = t;
};
const transpose = (ss) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      swap(ss, i * WIDTH + j, j * WIDTH + i);
    }
  }
};
```